# Javascript & FF-addon: How to save images to local disk without re-downloading them

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am creating a Firefox add-on using the Firefox add-on SDK. I would like to save all images in a page to a local disk. I tried attaching the following script to the active tab, and then send the result array back to main.js where I will save it to the disk.
The following code gives me a **SecurityError: The operation is insecure** error, probably because I load images from cross origin so **toDataURL** is blocked. I know I can just download the images to a location on the disk, but I don't want to re-download all the images as my browser already did it.
Is there another way to save the already loaded images to the local disk?

```
function getImage(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    //var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}

function getImages(outputDir){
    var coded_images = new Array();
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
        coded_images[i] = getImage(images[i]);
    }

    //send coded_images back to main.js
}
```

Thanks for the help!

**Update:**
The exception I am getting for the above code is:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "resource://myaddon/data/addon.js", line 18, in getImage
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message you got? and indicate the position in above code where exception was raised?

Answer (score 1):

Using `<canvas>` to save the images is actually not a great idea. This will rewrite the actual data and/or even change formats, also abandoning any meta data in the process.

Also, the security exception is expected due to the [same-origin policy](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl) being violated (exporting the image would enable the website to "read" it, although it contains parts from another origin). You'd have to run that code privileged (in a chrome XUL context), but that is hard to do in SDK code, anyway.

I suggest you have a look at how the regular context menu does the [Save Image](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/nsContextMenu.js#1248) stuff and work your way back from there. It might also cause additional CPU and memory load, due to the canvas itself and as the images have to be decoded, which they aren't necessarily at that point.

Or just save the image, which still might get it from the cache, depending on how you do it and the cache headers originally retrieved (e.g. XHR or `request` module saves won't normally bypass the cache).

Or use [`nsICacheStorageService`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/cache2/nsICacheStorageService.idl) and fall back to regular saving if not cached.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't manage using the method that the context menu does, so I followed an image download as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048689/save-website-image-using-a-firefox-addon-sdk?rq=1). I am not sure if it downloads from the cache though, as I see I can pass an **aCacheKey** argument to saveURI but I am passing null as I am not sure what I should pass. Also the example is missing the **aPrivacyContext** argument in saveURI, so passing null fixes this and downloads the image. The problem is the docs basically say I should never pass null.